# How can I calculate what percentile each value of a column is in? (Spark SQL)

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have the following table:

| Person | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 6.5 |
| 3 | 2.1 |
| 4 | 8.3 |
| 5 | 5.4 |

I have multiple people, each with just one score each. Each score is on a 10.0 point scale.

I would like to find out which percentile each person's score stands in. So a score of 6.5 for person 2, for example, is in the x percentile of people, and so on.

Couldn't figure out the syntax, would love some help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is a ratio of rank to count:

```
select rank(score) over (order by score) * 100.0 / count(*) over ()
```